sudo Login not getting visible in sugar13
we are experiencing an issue with the visibility of the sudo login footer while upgrading from Sugar10 to Sugar13,
The footer is not showing in Sugar13. I have checked the settings and documentation but couldn't find a relevant solution.
Could you please assist with this?
tried sugar13 documentation and other sugar communities for solution

By default there is no Sudo Login in SugarCRM, I think you are using a third party addon right?
e.g.: https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/oneclick-sudo-login
If you are using this plugin you have to wait until it gets compatible with Sugar v13. The latest version is only supporting Sugar v11.1.
At their Support area is already a Support Case for v13, but without response.
